# How can I optimize this code for creating TIFF files and/or what alternate libraries should I consider to improve performance?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, gdi+, tiff, parallel.foreach

I am creating a process to extract a TIFF, perform an operation on one of the images, and then rebuild the TIFF. The operation in the middle doesn't matter, however, extraction and rebuild are proving to be very costly in terms of processing.

```
const string tifPath = "14 page.TIFF";
MemoryStream[] imageStreams;
var stream = new MemoryStream();

//extract tiff
using (var imageFile = Image.FromFile(tifPath))
{
    var imagePageCount = imageFile.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    imageStreams = new MemoryStream[imagePageCount];
    var frameDimension = new FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

    for (var i = 0; i < imagePageCount; i++)
    {
        imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimension, i);
        var bmp = new Bitmap(imageFile);

        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        imageStreams[i] = stream;
    }
}

//build tiff
var encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
var encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i => i.MimeType == "image/tiff");
var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

stream = new MemoryStream();
var firstImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(imageStreams[0]));
firstImage.Save(stream, encoderInfo, encoderParameters);
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

for (var i = 1; i < imageStreams.Length; i++)
{
    var img = Image.FromStream(imageStreams[i]);
    firstImage.SaveAdd(img, encoderParameters);
}

encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
firstImage.SaveAdd(encoderParameters);
```

I found that clearing my stream helped in some places. With Microsoft's and other libraries (LeadTools and LibTiff) it averages around 5 seconds. I am not set on using a C# solution, but trying to find a way to squeeze it down as much as possible.

Comment: and your question would be?

Comment: How to make the current code faster. Libraries to use instead of GDI+.

Comment: @liori: I'm not asking for a simple opinion. I am looking for speed on a very slow process. I know image processing is costly, but all multipage TIFF information that I find from Google only addresses how to do them.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for Code Review than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a good way to parallelize the creation process. Attempting to build an Image from a MemoryStream that was built outside of the Parallel.ForEach only threw a general GDI+ error.

```
const string tifPath = "14 Page.TIFF";

//extract tiff
var imageFile = Image.FromFile(tifPath);
var imagePageCount = imageFile.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
var imageStreams = new Bitmap[imagePageCount];
var rangePartioner = Partitioner.Create(0, imagePageCount);
var frameDimension = new FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
imageFile.Dispose();

Parallel.ForEach(rangePartioner, (range, loopState) =>
{
    for (var i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        using (var imageFile2 = Image.FromFile(tifPath))
        {
            imageFile2.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimension, i);
            imageStreams[i] = new Bitmap(imageFile2);
        }
    }
});

//build tiff
var encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
var encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i => i.MimeType == "image/tiff");
var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long) EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

var stream2 = new MemoryStream();

using(var firstImage = imageStreams[0])
{
    firstImage.Save(stream2, encoderInfo, encoderParameters);

    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long) EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

    for (var i = 1; i < imageStreams.Length; i++)
    {
        firstImage.SaveAdd(imageStreams[i], encoderParameters);
    }

    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long) EncoderValue.Flush);
    firstImage.SaveAdd(encoderParameters);
}
```

This shaved off about 2 seconds. Still hunting for a good way to handle the second half.

EDIT: Added suggested changes of only converting the image and not saving it to a stream.
EDIT: Added remainder of fixes.

Comment: I have this piece and my attempts on the second half wrapped in try catch. The error message was only the "A generic error occurred in GDI+." I tried saving the initial new image and streams as files, but couldn't escape the useless error message.

Comment: 1) See if you can use Image.FromStream, instead of reading the file multiple times into memory, on each thread.

2) get rid of imageStreams[i] as it introduces false sharing between processors. your code is running right now "sequentially", as all the processors are starving for imageStreams[i]. You can use aggregate pattern(google Parallel foreach aggregate). Use thread local store for imageStreams and later put them into imageStreams array, if needed.

Comment: Image.FromStream is causing a generic GDI+ error when attempting SelectActiveFrame. Working with streams in this situation only seems to cause issues.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa: I've looked into using the Parallel.ForEach with an aggretor, but don't see a way to make this work for the building half. After your guidance in getting this from 5.5 s to 3.4s, I think this is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Start profiling your code and see which parts take time. It's hard to assume things. You can parallelize extracting TIFF, same with building. That would get you 4x speedup.

Comment: I'm only familiar with working through lists to spawn threads. How do you thread a process that is dependent on the order of pages?

Comment: Thanks. After noticing its speed I profiled the code. The analysis report pointed out that that Save and SaveAdd methods are very expensive.

Per your suggestion, I worked the extraction piece into a Parallel.ForEach that I posted as a potential answer. As for the creation process...not so much.

Comment: Why are you creating new bitmap? Does imageFile2.Save(stream, ImageFormat.bmp) not work?

Comment: I removed the array of MemoryStreams and replaced it with an array of Bitmaps. This yielded 500ms saved. So, down to 3.5s.